# How to return output as 'int' instead of 'numpy.int64'?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I have troubles understanding the difference between 'int' and 'numpy.int64'.

**Below is the question:**

I would need to complete the function explore_data to return a tuple, t, with the following elements.

```
t[0] - tuple - the shape of df
t[1] - pd.DataFrame - the first five rows of df
t[2] - dict - mapping year (int) to the number of films released that year (int)
The input df is a pd.DataFrame with the following columns:

'film_id' - unique integer associated with a film
'film_name' - the name of a film
'actor' - the name of an actor who starred in the film
'year' - the year which the film was released
Each row in df indicates an instance of an actor starring in a film, so it is possible that there will be multiple rows with the same 'film_name' and 'film_id'.
```

**My approach to this question:**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
def explore_data(df):
    res = list()
    res.append(df.shape) 
    res.append(df.head())
    gb = df.groupby('year').size()
    gb = gb.to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns = {0: 'Number'})
    d ={}
    for idx in range(len(gb)):
        y = gb['year'][idx]
        num = gb['Number'][idx]
        d[y] = num
    res.append(d)
    res = tuple(res)
    return res
```

However, I am facing the error:
[image]

Could someone please help to advise on the issue? Thank you!

Comment: t[2] is nowhere in your code. Please insert your code in your question rather than as an image. What is the full error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your keys and values of the dictionary while assigning them like this

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
def explore_data(df):
    res = list()
    res.append(df.shape) 
    res.append(df.head())
    gb = df.groupby('year').size()
    gb = gb.to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns = {0: 'Number'})
    d ={}
    for idx in range(len(gb)):
        y = int(gb['year'][idx])
        num = int(gb['Number'][idx])
        d[y] = num
    res.append(d)
    res = tuple(res)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the method `item()` converts a scalar-like numpy item to its Python equivalent.  It can be used for elements of arrays and for 0-dimension arrays.

```
>>> x[0], x[0].item()
(0.0, 0.0)
>>> type(x[0]), type(x[0].item())
(<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'float'>)

>>> y = np.zeros(())
>>> y
array(0.)
>>> y.item()
0.0
>>>
```